Update Excel table with a VBA SQL Script that uses CASE WHEN cmd
I have the next two Excel sheets that belong to the same excel file:
users:
----------------------------------------------
user_id  name   club       fanatic_of
1       Joe    Lakers
2       Frank  Bulls
3       George Atlantic
------------------------------------------------

affiliatons
------------------------------------------------
user_id  new_club  date
1       Bulls     2023/11/01
1       Atlantic  2024/11/02
2       Lakers    2021/10/01
---------------------------------------------

I want to update users and the Excel SQL cmd looks like:
UPDATE [users$] SET [fanatic_of] = 
    (CASE (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM  [affiliatons$]
          WHERE [affiliatons$].[user_id] = [users$].[user_id]
         ) 
        WHEN 0 THEN [users$].club
        WHEN 1 THEN [affiliatons$].new_club
        ELSE "undecided"
    END)

Which in "Normal" SQL should be:
UPDATE users SET fanatic_of = (
    CASE (SELECT COUNT (*)
          FROM  affiliatons
          WHERE affiliatons.user_id = users.user_id
         ) 
        WHEN 0 THEN users.club
        WHEN 1 THEN affiliatons.new_club
        ELSE "undecided"
    END )

I am getting a message "Wrong automation error" from Excel VBA so I need to ask:

Is my problem just an Excel VBA error? or is it also SQL?


is UDATE a typo? Should probably be UPDATE?

Sorry, it should be UPDATE for the question.... my problem persist. Thanks

Another way would be VBA:
Sub UpdateFanaticOf()
    Dim wsUsers As Worksheet
    Dim wsAffiliations As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowUsers As Long
    Dim lastRowAffiliations As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim userID As Long
    Dim countAffiliations As Long
    Dim newClub As String
    
    Set wsUsers = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("users")
    Set wsAffiliations = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("affiliations")
    
    lastRowUsers = wsUsers.Cells(wsUsers.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowAffiliations = wsAffiliations.Cells(wsAffiliations.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lastRowUsers
        userID = wsUsers.Cells(i, 1).Value
        countAffiliations = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsAffiliations.Range("A2:A" & lastRowAffiliations), userID)
        
        If countAffiliations = 0 Then
            wsUsers.Cells(i, 4).Value = wsUsers.Cells(i, 3).Value
        ElseIf countAffiliations = 1 Then
            newClub = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(userID, wsAffiliations.Range("A2:C" & lastRowAffiliations), 2, False)
            wsUsers.Cells(i, 4).Value = newClub
        Else
            wsUsers.Cells(i, 4).Value = "undecided"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub


If I understand you right you have no connection to an database and just two tables in excel. Then you can use power query.
Load Data into Power Query:
Load both users and affiliations tables into Power Query.
Transform Data in Power Query:
Perform a Group By operation on the affiliations table to count the number of affiliations per user.
Merge the resulting table with the users table on user_id.
Use a conditional column to set the fanatic_of column based on the count.
Steps in Power Query:
Load both tables:
Select each table and click "From Table/Range" under the "Data" tab.
Group By in affiliations:
Select the affiliations query, go to the "Transform" tab, click "Group By".
Group by user_id and add an aggregation to count user_id called Count.
Merge queries:
With the users query selected, go to the "Home" tab, click "Merge Queries".
Merge with the transformed affiliations table on user_id.
Add Conditional Column:
After merging, add a new conditional column to set the fanatic_of field based on the count of affiliations.
Use the conditions to check the count and set the value accordingly.
